# Tool to re-create state of smart contract locally

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, evm, python, tools

I would like to be able to simulate transactions with smart contracts based on their solidity source code. The process should be entirely automated.

While I am aware that some tools allow forking the chain at a given point in time, this generally requires me to start local nodes. It also does not scale well if I need information from many contracts at random block numbers.

Would there be some tool (ideally usable with Python) that allows mimicking a smart contract's state locally (and offline) based on its solidity source code? The idea would be that I can recreate transactions submitted to it and "roll-forward" its state to any point of time that I need it to without the need of forking and node providers. E.g., something like a local EVM runtime may do the trick but I am not sure how to set one up without also needing to run a node.

NOTE:
Upon researching this question I came across [py-evm](https://github.com/ethereum/py-evm), which seems to offer something in the direction I am looking for. The project looks solid, but it seems to still be under development and the documentation is a little sparse. Is there possibly a more mature tool around?

Comment: https://tenderly.co/ might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

There are `dump` and `dump-restore` commands in [**`0xweb`**](https://github.com/0xweb-org/0xweb) CLI tool. Depending on the local setup, here is an example for hardhat:

```bash
$ npm i 0xweb -g
$ 0xweb c dump 0x... --sources ./contracts/DumpDemo.sol --output ./dump/data/DumpDemo --chain hardhat
```

This generates two files:

1. `./dump/data/DumpDemo.json` - the `key-value` json of all contract's state variables
2. `./dump/data/DumpDemo.csv` - raw `slot-value` csv of contract's storage

Now, when you have deployed same contract under another address, you can populate the contracts storage with the dump back on-chain:

```bash
$ 0xweb c dump-restore 0x... --sources ./contracts/DumpDemo.sol --file ./dump/data/DumpDemo.csv --chain hardhat
```